# JQuery returns 2 different IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm currently using JQuery to retrieve a ASP.NET control, but for some reason jQuery seems to be finding all the controls with a similar name to the one I've specified. Here's an example of the code.

**HTML**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVat" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVatRate" runat="server" />
```

**JQuery**

```
var vat = $("[id*='txtVat']");
```

the `vat` returns both the `txtVat` and `txtVatRate` ASP textboxes. Is this right?? Is there another way around this so it gets the correct control without having to use the # sign (ie. `var vat = $("#txtVat");`). The reason I can not do it using the # is because it's using the ContentPlaceHolderID in ASP.

Comment: Remove * besides the IS, it should work

Comment: `*=` means `contains` - without it, it's the same as `#`  - can you elaborate how the ContentPlaceHolderID is affecting the ID as the *example* you've provided will work with `#`

Comment: Why not use: var vat = $("#txtVat");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) instead of the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
var vat = $("[id='txtVat']");
//          ---^^-----
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to use jquery with asp server control use ClientID it get exact id of your control.

```
var controlid = '<%=txtVat.ClientID%>'
var vat = $("[id='"+controlid+"']");
```

if you do not want to use ClientID then just remove * like this

```
var vat = $("[id='txtVat']");
```

I hope it's work for you.